# How to load a view on action with parameter?

Tags: jsf, glassfish, facelets

I know you can use `actionListeners` and use `setPropertyActionListener` which is ok, but I'm loading a view on action like this :

```
<p:commandButton  action="view_rate" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View/Edit" />
```

This button is inside a table and the `view_rate` gets loaded fine, but I want to be able to differ between a regular action to addcontact or a call from this specific button where the action should be to edit a contact.

I know I can create 2 different Facelets files, but since it's the same file I wanted to use the same file.

How can this be done? How can I send the parameter and recieve it?

Would something like `view_rate?somevar=somevalue` work?

I've tried adding

`<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{rateFile}" target="#{viewRateFileConfiguration.selectedRow}" 
/>`

And checking in the construcor of `viewRateFileConfiguration` which is the bean that handles the view file if `selectedRow` is set, but that didn't work and that doesn't seem like the best aproach to me anyway.

Comment: if you use `action="view_rate?includeViewParams=true&someValue=someVariable"`, `someValue` will be available on the destination as `#{param.someValue}`. Since you haven't provided any context or workable code in your question and your question mostly sounds like you're thinking out loud, what you do with that value on the destination page is entirely up to you

Comment: @kolossus Well writing like this gives syntax error that `;` is needed, and anyway i'm intrested in getting the parameter in a post construct method of the bean behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end I used  `<f:param value="somevalue" name="somevar" />`

And got it using regular parameter retervial.